# Minecraft LAN connecting to server for long time

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Whenever I try to play with my frined on LAN we get 2 problems. THe first being that if I  open an LAN world it doesnt even shop up on his server list, The second is when HE opens a world, It shows up but when I try to log in, It displays the message "Connecting to server" for around 20 seconds, then Shows the message "java.net.connectexception.minecraft" Ive tried allowing both computers through the firewall, and we're both playing on the same Wifi. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

if the world does not shop up in your list you can try the 'direct connect' function. its in the multiplayer screen.

to use it you will have to do the following:
 **1. find out the ip address of the hosting pc:**
 this can be done by typing 'ipconfig' in the command prompt. there find your IPv4 adress

 [to open the command prompt press WINDOWSKEY + R to open run and type 'cmd']
**2. Find the gateway of your LAN world**
When you open a world to LAN there is a number that shows in the chat, that is your gateway

**3. Entering the world**
now type the IPv4 Adress in the direct connect field followed by a : then the gateway, should look something like this [192.168.2.26:67154]
(note that these numbers can differ for you)

Comment: there is a guide with pictures here: https://www.evolvehq.com/games/minecraft/topics/guide-playing-minecraft-with-friends